# Calculate years based on months in 17 months graph in TypeScript (Highcharts)

Tags: typescript, highcharts

I have an issue I've been struggling with.

I have this column chart that spans 17 months - 12 months back and 6 months ahead.

Currently, it's May, and 12 months back is also May. Additionally, 6 months ahead is November.

In the tooltip, I need to show the specific year for each month.

I have two columns side by side, where one column should display the year prior to that particular year.

Ex. left bar->2022 right bar->2023 and so on.

[image: Image of the graph]

It has to be beside the header text here in the tooltip:
[Tooltip hover image](https://ibb.co/6WVbqsk)

My code:

```
private getSeriesDataFromGraphData(graphData: GetPreviousYearGraphData[]): Highcharts.PointOptionsObject[] {
    return graphData.map(({y, b2b, b2c, normal}) => ({y, b2b, b2c, normal}));
}

// Using the search-filters does not affect this graph. This graph is only affected when filtering between brands.
private renderOrderAmountCompareOnBrand(
    strCurrencyCode: string,
    arrCategories: string[],
    arrPrevSeriesDataStock: GetPreviousYearGraphData[],
    arrPrevSeriesDataPre: GetPreviousYearGraphData[],
    arrSeriesDataStock: GetPreviousYearGraphData[],
    arrSeriesDataPre: GetPreviousYearGraphData[]
) {
    // Get the series data for each set of graph data
    const prevSeriesDataStock = this.getSeriesDataFromGraphData(arrPrevSeriesDataStock);
    const prevSeriesDataPre = this.getSeriesDataFromGraphData(arrPrevSeriesDataPre);
    const seriesDataStock = this.getSeriesDataFromGraphData(arrSeriesDataStock);
    const seriesDataPre = this.getSeriesDataFromGraphData(arrSeriesDataPre);

    this.OrderAmountComparedOnBrandChart = Highcharts.chart('claimsOrderAmountPerSalesChannel', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Order amount compared on brand'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: arrCategories
            },
            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Brand order statistics'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    let strStyling = "display: flex; justify-content: space-between; gap: 20px;";
                    let startDate: Date = new Date();

                    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 12);

                    let year = startDate.getFullYear();

                    if (!this.series.name.includes('Previous year')) {
                        year += 1;
                    }

                    const GetPreviousYearGraphData = this.point as GetPreviousYearGraphData;

                    return `
                        <b>${this.point.category} | ${this.series.name} | ${year}</b><br><br>
                        <div style="${strStyling}">
                            <span><b>Sales staff:</b></span> ${Highcharts.numberFormat(GetPreviousYearGraphData.normal || 0, 0)} ${strCurrencyCode ?? ''}<br>
                        </div>
                        <div style="${strStyling}">
                            <span><b>B2B:</b></span> ${Highcharts.numberFormat(GetPreviousYearGraphData.b2b || 0, 0)} ${strCurrencyCode ?? ''}<br>
                        </div>
                        <div style="${strStyling}">
                            <span><b>B2C:</b></span> ${Highcharts.numberFormat(GetPreviousYearGraphData.b2c || 0, 0)} ${strCurrencyCode ?? ''}<br>
                        </div>
                        <div style="${strStyling}">
                            <span><b>Total:</b></span> ${Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y || 0, 0)} ${strCurrencyCode ?? ''}
                        </div>
                    `;
                },
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Stock Previous year',
                    data: prevSeriesDataStock,
                    stack: 'Stock1'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Pre Previous year',
                    data: prevSeriesDataPre,
                    stack: 'Stock1'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Stock',
                    data: seriesDataStock,
                    stack: 'Stock'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Pre',
                    data: seriesDataPre,
                    stack: 'Stock'
                }
            ] as SeriesOptionsType[]
        } as Options
    );
}
```

I tried a whole bunch of things, but i cant get it to calculate correctly.

Comment: I believe the "tooltip" is what you get when you hover your cursor over one of the bars.  Is that what you want to change?  That seems to be where your formatter code is right now.  I would think you'd want this information to be in the bottom X-Axis labels/series

Comment: I want it the tooltip beside the text "header" as seen here :) https://ibb.co/6WVbqsk

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(this)` from inside that tooltip formatter function?  That will show you everything available to you when creating tooltips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that the biggest problem is to calculate the proper year for the last year's months. To do that, you can check if a sum of `this.point.x - 12` and `currentDate.getMonth() + 1` is greater than `0` and set month depending on the calculations.

For example:

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      let strStyling = "display: flex; justify-content: space-between; gap: 20px;";
      const strCurrencyCode = '';

      const currentDate = new Date();
      const isCurrentYear = this.point.x - 12 + currentDate.getMonth() + 1 > 0;

      currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() - (isCurrentYear ? 12 : 24));

      let year = currentDate.getFullYear();

      if (!this.series.name.includes('Previous year')) {
        year += 1;
      }

      return `...`;
    },
    useHTML: true
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xf3Lu7qp/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter